# #1411 Incorrect datetime value: '01.07.2021' for function str_to_date

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I ran into such problems that in legacy database the date is stored in the format of a string, I try to convert but it does not work, can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

my sql:

```
SELECT id
FROM media
WHERE str_to_date(left(date,10), '%d%m%y') >= CURRENT_DATE AND
      uid=708715140
```

> err: Warning: #1411 Incorrect datetime value: '01.07.2021' for function str_to_date

Comment: The error seems pretty clear.  That date is not in the specified format.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because:

- you did not include the dots in the specified format
- you used `%y` which stands for 2-digit years instead of `%Y` which stands for 4-digit years.

The format that you must specify inside [`str_to_date()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) is `'%d.%m.%Y'`